# How to copy ellipse or polygon from one bitmap to another bitmap

Tags: delphi, gdi

How Can I copy an ellipse or polygon shape from one bitmap to another Bitmap. BitBlt is only useful for copying Rectangles.

I currently use GDI but If it is easier to use GDI+, I can use it. I only need a general guidance to show me the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could select an elliptic/polygon clip region into the target device context and then use BitBlt as usual.

```
var
  Rgn: HRGN;
  Points: array[0..2] of TPoint;
begin
  //Rgn := CreateEllipticRgn(0, 0, 100, 100);

  Points[0] := Point(0, 0);
  Points[1] := Point(50, 50);
  Points[2] := Point(50, 0);
  Rgn := CreatePolygonRgn(Points, 3, WINDING);

  SaveDC(Canvas.Handle);
  SelectClipRgn(Canvas.Handle, Rgn);
  DeleteObject(Rgn); // SelectClipRgn copies the region

  BitBlt(Canvas.Handle, 0, 0, 100, 100, BmpDC, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);

  RestoreDC(Canvas.Handle, -1);
end;
```

Comment: It seems SaveDC or RestoreDC is not really necessary. Because we are not changing brush, font, etc to restore it.

Comment: But you change the clip region. You could use GetClipRgn to get the current clip region, or you could call "SelectClipRgn(Canvas.Handle, 0)" to remove any clip region after the work is done.